# How can I see when a word has been added to the vocabulary?

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

Is there anyway to see when a word has been added to the vocabulary? Ideally I would like to list the custom words sorted by add date.

[image]

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to find the date when a word was added.

Neither in Dragon, nor in any Add-on that I have seen. Dragon does not log when word were added.

Comment: Thanks, do you know a program that could [export custom words and voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking on a regular basis](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7561/903)?

Comment: Added an answer there. You can do most of that through scripting (batch files or PowerShell). There's no program AFAIK, but I have added a possible alternative.